# Twitter app for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gui

I saw that on TVs (maybe its Apple TV?) there is an app which displays some interesting or motivational tweets from twitter. I need to just hang a LCD display with Rpi on a wall and leave it running and it should do just this simple thing. Is there any app which could do this?

Comment: I really despise hearing people say things like _it should do just this simple thing_. Such a thing isn't really that simple. Who's going to curate the tweets? Is there an account to follow, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can come up with.

Log into one of these sites: Twitterfall, Twitter Fontana or Visible Tweet.
Do all the corresponding configuration.
And leave your browser running on full screen (F11).

Comment: Great answer. I will go this way and set up some autostart.